# Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle' line: 10; path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

Tags: react-native, expo, gradlew, eas

When I use `eas build` This happen.

`
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip

10

%.

20%

30%.

40%.

50%

60%.

70%.

80%.

90%.

100%

Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html

To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.

Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

[stderr]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

[stderr]

- Where:

[stderr]

Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle' line: 10

[stderr]

- What went wrong:

[stderr]

A problem occurred evaluating settings 'JOiNTOMEET'.

[stderr]

> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'

[stderr]

- Try:

[stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

[stderr]

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[stderr]

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[stderr]

BUILD FAILED in 20s

Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
`

what i do ? i really need to run `eas build`

Comment: How did you fix plz ?

Answer (score 0):

What i mostly do in these situations is making sure every package is installed via the command `npm i`, after that i make sure my android folder is correct by running `cd android && ./gradlew clean`. If an error occurs, it will give you more detail on where it is.